# firefox OpenBSD 5.6 Error no display specified

Tags: firefox, openbsd, shared-library

I bought the 3 CD set for OpenBSD 5.6 and installed OpenBSD 5.6, but it may have used an http site. The installation was successful, signify was happy. Then, I installed the packages on an i386 notebook. Now, here's what happens:

```
# firefox <return>
firefox:/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.57.0: /usr/local/lib/libestdc++.so.16.0 : WARNING: symbol(_ZN11_gnu_debug17_S_debug_messagesE) size mismatch, relink your program Error: no display specified
# apropos relink <return>
# apropos mismatch <return>
```

I am a novice OpenBSD/UNIX user. What needs to be done to clear this WARNING/ERROR hurdle?

Answer (score 2):

You have installed firefox for openbsd 5.7. but your system is 5.6
Do remove wrong firefox version and add proper one from 5.6 pkg tree

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling you might have installed the wrong package. pkg_delete the current package and pkg_add the correct one. `man pkg_add’ for details.